# Sufficient statistics for $p$ for a random sample from $\text{Ber}(p)$ distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, estimation, binomial-distribution

Let $X_1,X_2, X_3$ be a random sample from Bernoulli distribution $B(p)$. Which of the following is sufficient statistic for $p$ ?

$(A)\ \ X_{1}^{2}+X_{2}^{2}+X_{3}^{2}$

$(B) \ \ X_1+2X_{2}+X_{3}$

$(C)\ \ 2X_1-X_{2}-X_{3}$

$(D) \ \ X_1+X_{2}$

$(E)\ \ 3X_1+2X_{2}-4X_{3}$

We know $T=\sum_i^3 X_i$ is sufficient statistic for $p$ via Neymann Factorization theorem.

The reasoning for different options.

$(A)$ It's not a one-one function of sufficient statistic $T$ (If it was $T^2$ , was it sufficient statistic then? My answer is yes because it is one to one function of sufficient statistic our random variable is positive am I right?).

$(B)X_1+X_{2}+X_{3}+X_{2}$ It contains original statistic therefor it is suffient statistic for $p$.

$(D)$ It doesn't include $X_3$ So it's not sufficient statistic for $p$

All other options include subtraction in it so I ruled out all of them.

I think my reasoning is not very good I lack some intuition behind finding sufficient statistic. Correct me here, please.

Comment: Actually it seems only option E is correct.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Can you tell me how? One more thing is that I took an example in B such that $T=2$ and my conditional distribution of sample give T=2 is not independent of the parameter.

Comment: No one answers my question. :(

Comment: @StubbornAtom Ok bro :)

Comment: See my edit. Option (A) is also correct.

Comment: @StubbornAtom bhai how is this possible previous year it came only one option is correct.

Comment: You check the values of $X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2$ and $X_1+X_2+X_3$ and say whether there is a bijection between the two or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T=X_1+X_2+X_3$ is a minimal sufficient statistic for $p$, implying that it is a function of every other sufficient statistic, option (D) is eliminated.

Now $X_i^2$ is a one-to-one function function of $X_i$ because $X_i\in\{0,1\}$ for each $i$.

So $X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2$ is also a one-to-one function of $T$, implying that the former is sufficient for $p$. (Thanks to @Alex for pointing this out)

For the remaining options I create a table of the possible values that the statistics can take:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline (X_1,X_2,X_3)&T_1=X_1+2X_2+X_3&T_2=2X_1-X_2-X_3&T_3=3X_1+2X_2-4X_3\\ \hline(0,0,0)&0&0&0\\ 
\hline(0,0,1)&1&-1&-4\\ 
\hline(0,1,0)&2&-1&2\\ 
\hline (0,1,1)&3&-2&-2\\
\hline (1,0,0)&1&2&3\\
\hline (1,0,1)&2&1&-1\\
\hline (1,1,0)&3&1&5\\
\hline (1,1,1)&4&0&1\\
\hline
\end{array}

I am looking whether $T_1,T_2,T_3$ are one-to-one functions of the sample $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ or not. If they are, then they are sufficient statistics. If you can see right away that the only bijection is $$T_3:\{0,1\}^3\to\{-4,-2,\ldots,3,5\}$$, then you are done. Because a bijection with the sample implies that observing $T_3(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ and observing $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ are equivalent. In other words, $T_3$ is a sufficient statistic for $p$.

Alternatively, if you consider the case $T_1=2$, you will find that the conditional distribution $P(\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}\mid T_1)$ depends on $p$. Similar argument holds for $T_2$ if you consider the case $T_2=0$. Also it is apparent from the table above that $P(\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}\mid T_3)$ is independent of $p$ for all possible values of $T_3$, because $T_3$ takes 8 distinct values corresponding to 8 different tuples.

I used the following threads for reference:

- [Verification of sufficiency of a linear combination of the sample $(X_i)_{i\ge1}$ where $X_i\stackrel{\text{i.i.d}}\sim\text{Ber}(\theta)$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358303/verification-of-sufficiency-of-a-linear-combination-of-the-sample-x-i-i-ge1?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Sufficiency or Insufficiency](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130837/sufficiency-or-insufficiency?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Bhai this question came in 2 marks. You sure there isn't any other way. Seems like in exam  it will be time-consuming.

Comment: @Daman I am aware this is an MCQ question. If you are given that there is only one correct answer, then the job becomes slightly quicker. The only checking is between three possible options. So if you can detect which among the three is a bijective function of $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$, you have an answer. Depends on how exactly can you detect the bijection - just by looking at the statistic or by drawing a table. I am not saying this is the only way to solve the problem; there may well be a faster/easier solution.

Comment: Ok bhai .  Let me understand this one first. I didn't get it yet.

Comment: I understood it bhai. Thanks!

Comment: $T_3:\{0,1\}^3..$ What does that degree$ 3$ represent ?

Comment: @Daman I used it to denote the set of all 3 tuples of $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Bhai bounty laga di.

Comment: If $X$ is drawn from a $B(p)$ distribution then $X^2 = X$ ($X$ can only take the values $0$ or $1$). So $X_1^2 + X_2^2 + X_3^2 = X_1 + X_2 + X_3 = T(X)$. So (A) is a sufficient statistic.

Comment: @Alex You are right that (A) is sufficient. That equality is in distribution though. I somehow did not realise that $X_i^2$ is a one-to-one function of $X_i$ in the Bernoulli case. Thank you.